# Create jar file from batch script

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar, cmd

I need to create .jar using .bat. When I run this command from cmd it is ok:

```
jar -cMf ../sp.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF *class
```

but when I run batch file (.bat) with this command inside i says:

```
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What should I do? When I try in cmd run javac or jar it is ok.

Comment: Set your path or use the fully qualified command name (including the path).

Answer (score 1):

The command you give is a little confusing; by giving "M" as parameter you specify that you want to create a jar without a Manifest. By using "m" it means that you want to create a jar and then specify the manifest.

Please see http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-the-jar-command/

Also, I would use "jar cmf" instead of "jar -cMf" (whithout the "-").

In the end, try using the full path to where you have your jdk, something like: "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.your.version\bin"

Comment: There are (at least) three alternate solutions to resolve the error:
(a) Use the full path to the jar executable in the .bat file
(b) Execute the bat file through a shortcut and set the "start in" folder to the  location of the jar file
(c) Modify the system paths to include the location of the jar executable hence rendering future references to the full path unneccessary.